# Are there alternatives for HCPL3700?

Tags: digital-logic, ac, dc, isolation

The [HCPL3700](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/HCPL3700-D.pdf) seems to be a wonderful IC for sensing all kinds of input voltages, however it is a bit pricey so I was looking for alternatives. Alternatives I'm looking for should not contain components like transformers or other not widely used or large components. Isolation is preferable.

One alternative I found is using X2 capacitors combined with a Z-diode, resistors and an optocoupler, however X2 capacitors have a pretty huge footprint and the circuit is not made for sensing DC voltages.

Comment: you could also use an isolation opamp. You give different input signals and get the differential between them. This way you can sense the input voltages. I tried this before. If you want I can share the LT spice circuit diagram.

Comment: Two years ago I bought from TaoTao (sort of AliExpress) 30 pieces of HPCL3700 at CNY2 each. I sample tested and found everything OK. I used it to detect AC power and also found everything OK. HPCL3700 A3700 DIP8 - TaoBao CNY2 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=219744&p=1357430&hilit=hcpl3700#p1357535

Comment: HPCL3700 datasheet is a bit hard to read though. It took me some two hobbyist weeks to figure out by trials and errors, how to use it: References:(1) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=219744&hilit=hcpl3700&start=75#p1357769
(2) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=219744&hilit=hcpl3700&start=75#p1358147
(3) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=219744&hilit=hcpl3700&start=100#p1359104

Answer (score 3):

So, this is a combination of an optocoupler and a threshold circuit.

Optocouplers are probably the cheapest solution to proper isolation for anything that might be too low in frequency to pass through a capacitor. There's thousands of them, and you'll likely find many many that would suit your needs on the output side.

Threshold detectors there are plenty, and you'd need to find one that fits your use case.

So, essentially, there's nothing stopping you from building this device for yourself from a threshold detector in any form (from Zener diodes to opamp-based voltage comparators to discharge tubes to plain resistive voltage dividers) and an optocoupler. "A little pricey" might simply be the price other engineers are willing to pay to simplify their design.